# Помогите улучшить код создания клавиатуры для бота

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, .net-6

Подскажите можно ли сделать код приведенный ниже более грамотно?
.Net 6.0

```
public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup KeyboardMarkup()
{
    var keyboard = new List <KeyboardButton[]> ();
    List <string> arr = new();

    //Добавляем строчки для теста
    arr.Add("Key1");
    arr.Add("Key2");
    arr.Add("Key3");
    //arr.Add("Key4");

    //При четном arr выполняем код:
    if (arr.Count % 2 == 0) {
        //Заполняем keyboard данными из arr по 2шт
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i += 2)
        {
            keyboard.Add(new KeyboardButton[] { arr[i], arr[i + 1] });
        }
    }
    //При нечетном List arr выполняем код:
    else
    {
        //Заполняем keyboard данными из arr по 2шт
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count - 1; i += 2) {
            keyboard.Add(new KeyboardButton[] { arr[i], arr[i + 1] });
        }
        //Т.к. выполняется код при нечетном кол-ве arr добавляем необработанное последнее значение arr
        keyboard.Add(new KeyboardButton[] { arr.Last() });
    }
    return new(keyboard);
}
```

upd

```
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;

namespace CourseMarketBot
{
    internal class GenMenu
    {
        public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup KeyboardMarkup()
        {
            List<KeyboardButton> arr = new();
            //using var context = new Context();

            //Это для моей БД
            //foreach (var item in context.MenuItems)
            //    if (item.Status)
            //        arr.Add(item.Name);

            //Для теста т.к. пример без подключения к БД
            arr.Add("Key1");
            arr.Add("Key2");
            arr.Add("Key3");
            //arr.Add("Key4");
            
            return new(arr.Chunk(2).ToList()) { ResizeKeyboard = true };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста ознакомьтесь и поправьте вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info

Comment: @Kromster, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/178988

Comment: @inews, зачем убрал метку [tag:инспекция-кода]?

Comment: @Qwertiy когда постите ссылки, пожалуйста сопровождайте их пояснительным текстом. Мне ваша ссылка сама по себе ни о чем не говорит, например.

Comment: @Kromster, ссылка на то, что вопрос соответствует тематике.

Comment: @Qwertiy не понимаю, зачем вы мне это приводите. Вопрос соответствует тематике, я лишь указал на то, что его стоило бы конкретизировать последовав руководству из описания соответствующей метки (на которую дал ссылку).

Comment: @Kromster, сорри, кажется я невнимательно посмотрел твой комментарий. Хотя, вообще-то не понимаю, что требовалось поправить кроме добавления самой метки и улучшения заголовка.

Comment: @Qwertiy метка уже была. Но не было описания целей кода и целей оптимизации.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В dotnet 6 появилась функция `.Chunk(int size)`, которая преобразует последовательность как раз так, как вам надо.

```cs
keyboard = arr.Chunk(2).ToList();
```

Comment: Что?? Вы предугадали мой ответ

Comment: Спасибо, у меня получилось вот так, см. 1 сообщение*

Comment: @inews посмотрел ваш код, там лишняя строка `var keyboard = new List<KeyboardButton[]>();`, вы ее вообще никак не используете.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> List <string> arr = new();
>
> //Добавляем строчки для теста
> arr.Add("Key1");
> arr.Add("Key2");
> arr.Add("Key3");
> //arr.Add("Key4");
> ```

```
List <string> arr { "Key1", "Key2", "Key3", /* "Key4" */ };
```

Но вообще, при том, что строки задаются в самом методе, я не понимаю, зачем городить всю это логику. Можно ведь просто взять и полностью всё захардкодить - получится гораздо проще:

```
public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup KeyboardMarkup()
{
  return new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
  (
    new List<KeyboardButton[]>
    (
      new KeyboardButton[] { "Key1", "Key2" },
      new KeyboardButton[] { "Key3" },
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup KeyboardMarkup() => new(new List<string>(){"Key1", "Key2", "Key3",}.Chunk(2).ToList());
```